# PHP Prepared Statement fetch size

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to find a way to get the amount of rows that were fetched when using a `Select` query from PHP.

Code snippet:

```
$conn = new mysqli("8.8.4.4", "reader", "youwishyouknew", "perf_test");
if($conn->connect_errno){
    echo 'Failed to connect to Database: ('.$conn->connect_errno.') '.$conn->connect_error;
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT score, date FROM tbl_runs WHERE client_id = '.$_POST['device'].' AND os_id = '.$_POST['os'].' AND test_id = '.$_POST['test'].' ORDER BY date ASC';
    $results = $conn->prepare($query);
    $results->execute();
    $results->bind_results($test_score, $test_date);
    while($results->fetch(){
        $tests[0][] = $test_date;
        $tests[1][] = $test_date;
    }
}
```

This all works just fine. But I am interested if it is possible to to see how many results are actually returned without counting how many times `fetch()` is called?

Comment: You can just use rowCount.

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli`, you **must** use the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to introduce `$_POST` data into your queries without creating enormous [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You cannot use string concatenation to compose queries without [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mysqli, you can use `$results->num_rows`:

```
$results = $conn->prepare($query);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_results($test_score, $test_date);
while($results->fetch(){
    $tests[0][] = $test_date;
    $tests[1][] = $test_date;
}
$count = $results->num_rows;
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Keep in mind that in any MySQL client, the correct number of rows in the result is not known until all rows have been fetched.  So you must read `num_rows` *after* the while loop in the example above.

Exception: if you use `$results->store_result()` after `execute()`, this makes the MySQL client "download" all the rows internally, and then subsequent `fetch()` calls just iterate over the internally cached result.  If you use this feature, you can read the `num_rows` value at any time:

```
$results = $conn->prepare($query);
$results->execute();
$results->store_result();
$count = $results->num_rows;
$results->bind_results($test_score, $test_date);
while($results->fetch(){
    $tests[0][] = $test_date;
    $tests[1][] = $test_date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
$count = $results->rowCount();
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is a PDO method. The OP is using mysqli, so that won't work.  He/she needs to use [`$results->num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) for a mysqli statement.

Comment: Silly me, I missed the first line completely, and just looked at $results->fetch(). You're right.

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to to see how many results are actually returned without counting how many times fetch() is called?

Sure.

```
$count = count($tests[0]);
```